# Can LibGDX projects be run in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, libgdx, sublimetext3, project

I use Sublime Text 3 as an IDE for everything. However, a friend has asked me to help him with his LibGDX project. LibGDX says I have to use IntelliJ in order to build it.

Is there a way to open and run LibGDX projects in Sublime Text 3?

Comment: Possible or not it's not advisable. Go for Android studio or at least Eclipse and save your self from tone of problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This link](https://www.codejava.net/coding/how-to-compile-and-run-a-java-program-with-sublime-text-3) talks about how to compile and run a Java program with Sublime Text 3. But Sublime Text, VS Code etc are lightweight IDEs at best. They won't be able to match IntelliJ when it comes to productive Java coding.

Comment: Okay, I installed IntelliJ instead.

Answer (score 2):

libGDX projects are built using Gradle, so all you have to do is execute `gradlew desktop:run` from the command line, which should build and run the game just fine.

Make sure to execute the command from the project's root directory, you will be using the Gradle wrapper executable included with the project.

More information can be found here: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gradle-on-the-Commandline